# Insert into database from array of checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox, insert

i have a form that contains checkboxes. I've named the checkboxes as stream[], so it's an array of checkboxes.

I would like to insert the checkbox values if it is checked.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="stream[]" value="survey" id="svy"/>Survey</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="stream[]" value="write_review" id="wr">Write Review</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="stream[]" value="fb post" id="fbp">Facebook Post</p>.
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should not be that difficult, check out this [link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) and [this](http://www.blog.highub.com/php/php-core/insert-checkbox-values-to-mysql-using-php/). But the essential idea is to know the right way to access the checkbox. Below is the general idea, a little homework for you to do the necessary changes to the code below to suit your situation.

```
$streams = $_POST['stream'];
foreach ($streams as $stream) {
  if ($stream == $value)
  {
     // checked value.
  }
}
```